# Converting punycode with dash character to Unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode, punycode

I need to convert the punycode `NIATO-OTABD` to `nñiñatoñ`.

I found [a text converter in JavaScript](http://0xcc.net/jsescape/) the other day, but the punycode conversion doesn't work if there's a dash in the middle.

Any suggestion to fix the "dash" issue?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I took the time to create the punycode below. It it based on the C code in RFC 3492. To use it with domain names you have to remove/add `xn--` from/to the input/output to/from decode/encode.

The `utf16-class` is necessary to convert from JavaScripts internal character representation to unicode and back.

There are also `ToASCII` and `ToUnicode` functions to make it easier to convert between puny-coded IDN and ASCII.

```js
//Javascript Punycode converter derived from example in RFC3492.
//This implementation is created by some@domain.name and released into public domain
var punycode = new function Punycode() {
    // This object converts to and from puny-code used in IDN
    //
    // punycode.ToASCII ( domain )
    // 
    // Returns a puny coded representation of "domain".
    // It only converts the part of the domain name that
    // has non ASCII characters. I.e. it dosent matter if
    // you call it with a domain that already is in ASCII.
    //
    // punycode.ToUnicode (domain)
    //
    // Converts a puny-coded domain name to unicode.
    // It only converts the puny-coded parts of the domain name.
    // I.e. it dosent matter if you call it on a string
    // that already has been converted to unicode.
    //
    //
    this.utf16 = {
        // The utf16-class is necessary to convert from javascripts internal character representation to unicode and back.
        decode:function(input){
            var output = [], i=0, len=input.length,value,extra;
            while (i < len) {
                value = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                if ((value & 0xF800) === 0xD800) {
                    extra = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                    if ( ((value & 0xFC00) !== 0xD800) || ((extra & 0xFC00) !== 0xDC00) ) {
                        throw new RangeError("UTF-16(decode): Illegal UTF-16 sequence");
                    }
                    value = ((value & 0x3FF) << 10) + (extra & 0x3FF) + 0x10000;
                }
                output.push(value);
            }
            return output;
        },
        encode:function(input){
            var output = [], i=0, len=input.length,value;
            while (i < len) {
                value = input[i++];
                if ( (value & 0xF800) === 0xD800 ) {
                    throw new RangeError("UTF-16(encode): Illegal UTF-16 value");
                }
                if (value > 0xFFFF) {
                    value -= 0x10000;
                    output.push(String.fromCharCode(((value >>>10) & 0x3FF) | 0xD800));
                    value = 0xDC00 | (value & 0x3FF);
                }
                output.push(String.fromCharCode(value));
            }
            return output.join("");
        }
    }

    //Default parameters
    var initial_n = 0x80;
    var initial_bias = 72;
    var delimiter = "\x2D";
    var base = 36;
    var damp = 700;
    var tmin=1;
    var tmax=26;
    var skew=38;
    var maxint = 0x7FFFFFFF;

    // decode_digit(cp) returns the numeric value of a basic code 
    // point (for use in representing integers) in the range 0 to
    // base-1, or base if cp is does not represent a value.

    function decode_digit(cp) {
        return cp - 48 < 10 ? cp - 22 : cp - 65 < 26 ? cp - 65 : cp - 97 < 26 ? cp - 97 : base;
    }

    // encode_digit(d,flag) returns the basic code point whose value
    // (when used for representing integers) is d, which needs to be in
    // the range 0 to base-1. The lowercase form is used unless flag is
    // nonzero, in which case the uppercase form is used. The behavior
    // is undefined if flag is nonzero and digit d has no uppercase form. 

    function encode_digit(d, flag) {
        return d + 22 + 75 * (d < 26) - ((flag != 0) << 5);
        //  0..25 map to ASCII a..z or A..Z 
        // 26..35 map to ASCII 0..9
    }
    //** Bias adaptation function **
    function adapt(delta, numpoints, firsttime ) {
        var k;
        delta = firsttime ? Math.floor(delta / damp) : (delta >> 1);
        delta += Math.floor(delta / numpoints);

        for (k = 0; delta > (((base - tmin) * tmax) >> 1); k += base) {
                delta = Math.floor(delta / ( base - tmin ));
        }
        return Math.floor(k + (base - tmin + 1) * delta / (delta + skew));
    }

    // encode_basic(bcp,flag) forces a basic code point to lowercase if flag is zero,
    // uppercase if flag is nonzero, and returns the resulting code point.
    // The code point is unchanged if it is caseless.
    // The behavior is undefined if bcp is not a basic code point.

    function encode_basic(bcp, flag) {
        bcp -= (bcp - 97 < 26) << 5;
        return bcp + ((!flag && (bcp - 65 < 26)) << 5);
    }

    // Main decode
    this.decode=function(input,preserveCase) {
        // Dont use utf16
        var output=[];
        var case_flags=[];
        var input_length = input.length;

        var n, out, i, bias, basic, j, ic, oldi, w, k, digit, t, len;

        // Initialize the state: 

        n = initial_n;
        i = 0;
        bias = initial_bias;

        // Handle the basic code points: Let basic be the number of input code 
        // points before the last delimiter, or 0 if there is none, then
        // copy the first basic code points to the output.

        basic = input.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
        if (basic < 0) basic = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < basic; ++j) {
            if(preserveCase) case_flags[output.length] = ( input.charCodeAt(j) -65 < 26);
            if ( input.charCodeAt(j) >= 0x80) {
                throw new RangeError("Illegal input >= 0x80");
            }
            output.push( input.charCodeAt(j) );
        }

        // Main decoding loop: Start just after the last delimiter if any
        // basic code points were copied; start at the beginning otherwise. 

        for (ic = basic > 0 ? basic + 1 : 0; ic < input_length; ) {

            // ic is the index of the next character to be consumed,

            // Decode a generalized variable-length integer into delta,
            // which gets added to i. The overflow checking is easier
            // if we increase i as we go, then subtract off its starting 
            // value at the end to obtain delta.
            for (oldi = i, w = 1, k = base; ; k += base) {
                    if (ic >= input_length) {
                        throw RangeError ("punycode_bad_input(1)");
                    }
                    digit = decode_digit(input.charCodeAt(ic++));

                    if (digit >= base) {
                        throw RangeError("punycode_bad_input(2)");
                    }
                    if (digit > Math.floor((maxint - i) / w)) {
                        throw RangeError ("punycode_overflow(1)");
                    }
                    i += digit * w;
                    t = k <= bias ? tmin : k >= bias + tmax ? tmax : k - bias;
                    if (digit < t) { break; }
                    if (w > Math.floor(maxint / (base - t))) {
                        throw RangeError("punycode_overflow(2)");
                    }
                    w *= (base - t);
            }

            out = output.length + 1;
            bias = adapt(i - oldi, out, oldi === 0);

            // i was supposed to wrap around from out to 0,
            // incrementing n each time, so we'll fix that now: 
            if ( Math.floor(i / out) > maxint - n) {
                throw RangeError("punycode_overflow(3)");
            }
            n += Math.floor( i / out ) ;
            i %= out;

            // Insert n at position i of the output: 
            // Case of last character determines uppercase flag: 
            if (preserveCase) { case_flags.splice(i, 0, input.charCodeAt(ic -1) -65 < 26);}

            output.splice(i, 0, n);
            i++;
        }
        if (preserveCase) {
            for (i = 0, len = output.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (case_flags[i]) {
                    output[i] = (String.fromCharCode(output[i]).toUpperCase()).charCodeAt(0);
                }
            }
        }
        return this.utf16.encode(output);
    };

    //** Main encode function **

    this.encode = function (input,preserveCase) {
        //** Bias adaptation function **

        var n, delta, h, b, bias, j, m, q, k, t, ijv, case_flags;

        if (preserveCase) {
            // Preserve case, step1 of 2: Get a list of the unaltered string
            case_flags = this.utf16.decode(input);
        }
        // Converts the input in UTF-16 to Unicode
        input = this.utf16.decode(input.toLowerCase());

        var input_length = input.length; // Cache the length

        if (preserveCase) {
            // Preserve case, step2 of 2: Modify the list to true/false
            for (j=0; j < input_length; j++) {
                case_flags[j] = input[j] != case_flags[j];
            }
        }

        var output=[];


        // Initialize the state: 
        n = initial_n;
        delta = 0;
        bias = initial_bias;

        // Handle the basic code points: 
        for (j = 0; j < input_length; ++j) {
            if ( input[j] < 0x80) {
                output.push(
                    String.fromCharCode(
                        case_flags ? encode_basic(input[j], case_flags[j]) : input[j]
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        h = b = output.length;

        // h is the number of code points that have been handled, b is the
        // number of basic code points 

        if (b > 0) output.push(delimiter);

        // Main encoding loop: 
        //
        while (h < input_length) {
            // All non-basic code points < n have been
            // handled already. Find the next larger one: 

            for (m = maxint, j = 0; j < input_length; ++j) {
                ijv = input[j];
                if (ijv >= n && ijv < m) m = ijv;
            }

            // Increase delta enough to advance the decoder's
            // <n,i> state to <m,0>, but guard against overflow: 

            if (m - n > Math.floor((maxint - delta) / (h + 1))) {
                throw RangeError("punycode_overflow (1)");
            }
            delta += (m - n) * (h + 1);
            n = m;

            for (j = 0; j < input_length; ++j) {
                ijv = input[j];

                if (ijv < n ) {
                    if (++delta > maxint) return Error("punycode_overflow(2)");
                }

                if (ijv == n) {
                    // Represent delta as a generalized variable-length integer: 
                    for (q = delta, k = base; ; k += base) {
                        t = k <= bias ? tmin : k >= bias + tmax ? tmax : k - bias;
                        if (q < t) break;
                        output.push( String.fromCharCode(encode_digit(t + (q - t) % (base - t), 0)) );
                        q = Math.floor( (q - t) / (base - t) );
                    }
                    output.push( String.fromCharCode(encode_digit(q, preserveCase && case_flags[j] ? 1:0 )));
                    bias = adapt(delta, h + 1, h == b);
                    delta = 0;
                    ++h;
                }
            }

            ++delta, ++n;
        }
        return output.join("");
    }

    this.ToASCII = function ( domain ) {
        var domain_array = domain.split(".");
        var out = [];
        for (var i=0; i < domain_array.length; ++i) {
            var s = domain_array[i];
            out.push(
                s.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/) ?
                "xn--" + punycode.encode(s) :
                s
            );
        }
        return out.join(".");
    }
    this.ToUnicode = function ( domain ) {
        var domain_array = domain.split(".");
        var out = [];
        for (var i=0; i < domain_array.length; ++i) {
            var s = domain_array[i];
            out.push(
                s.match(/^xn--/) ?
                punycode.decode(s.slice(4)) :
                s
            );
        }
        return out.join(".");
    }
}();


// Example of usage:
domain.oninput = function() {
    var input = domain.value
    var ascii = punycode.ToASCII(input)
    var display = punycode.ToUnicode(ascii)
    domain_ascii.value = ascii
    domain_display.value = display
}
```

```html
<p>Try with your own data</p>

<label>
  <div>Input domain</div>
  <div><input id="domain" type="text"></div>
</label>
<div>Ascii: <output id="domain_ascii"></div>
<div>Display: <output id="domain_display"></div>
```

**Licence:**

From RFC3492:

> Disclaimer and license
>
> Regarding this entire document or any portion of it (including the pseudocode and C code), the author makes no guarantees and is not responsible for any damage resulting from its use. The author grants irrevocable permission to anyone to use, modify, and distribute it in any way that does not diminish the rights of anyone else to use, modify, and distribute it, provided that redistributed derivative works do not contain misleading author or version information. Derivative works need not be licensed under similar terms.

I put my work in this punycode and utf16 in the public domain. It would be nice to get an email telling me in what project you use it.

**The scope of the code**

*Each TLD has rules for which code points are allowed. The scope of the code below is to encode and decode a string between punycode and the internal encoding used by javascript regardes of those rules.
Depending on your use case, you may need to filter the string.
For example, 0xFE0F: Variation Selector-16, an invisible code point that specifies that the previous character should be displayed with emoji presentation.
If you search for "allowed code points in IDN" you should find several projects that can help you filter the string.*

Comment: users can't email you when you don't provide a valid email address in your user page profile somewhere .. the tradition is to put it in the "about me" field

Comment: @Jeff: When I wrote that I thought it was already there. Fixed.

Comment: Awesome work, _some_! This is one of the Punycode implementations that I compared while writing [my own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-free-javascript-for-punycode-to-unicode-conversion/8110556#8110556). I hope you don’t mind I re-used your UTF16 class :)

Comment: @Mathias Bynens: Thank you! I have no problems with you reusing the code, that¨s what it's here for! I am however curious why you felt you needed to write your own? Did you find something wrong with it?

Comment: @some Wonderful, thanks! I was trying to get a better understanding of the Punycode algorithm, and because I couldn’t find a fully documented and unit-tested library (in any programming language) I went ahead, wrote my own, and optimized it for performance.

Comment: @Mathias Bynens: I assume that you have read RFC 3492 for the documentation of punycode. I admire your enthusiasm and curiosity. Have you some numbers of how much faster your implementation is compared to mine?

Comment: @some Yes, I did read RFC 3492 and RFC 5891 :) On fact, I believe I found a bug in RFC 3492: http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3492&eid=3026 As for performance: these may not all apply to your implementation, but here are some of the performance tests that I ran while working on it: http://jsperf.com/browse/mathias-bynens Here are the other implementations that I’ve based my work on: https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js#readme

Comment: I love you guys. You're so freak.

Comment: I will use it in my social network to autodetect urls. https://github.com/kuchumovn/sociopathy

Comment: @some, would you please state a license for the script?  I ported PL/SQL version from your code and would like to publish on github.

Comment: @ernix You are free to do whatever you want with the code. I makes no guarantees and is not responsible for any damage resulting from its use. You would make me happier if you put a link to your work in a comment to my answer! :)

Comment: Thanks. I found this useful for converting HTML5 input type="email" IDN email addresses back to unicode.

Comment: @PHPGuru Happy that you found it useful. :)

Comment: @some This answer is awesome, but I have one problem with it. When I want to convert for example domain `i❤️tacos.ws` to punycode, this code convert it to this `xn--itacos-i50d6220o.ws`, but the proper encode is `xn--itacos-i50d.ws`. Anyone have any idea why it happens?

Comment: @test Sorry for the late answer. You have an extra code point after the heart (0x2764) with code 0xFE0F. That is a Variation Selector-16, an invisible codepoint which specifies that the preceding character should be displayed with emoji presentation. Only required if the preceding character defaults to text presentation. It was approved as part of Unicode 3.2 in 2002, but should not be used in punycode.

Comment: @some Thanks for your answer! Is there any solution to ignore this?

Comment: @test You have to filter the input before calling this function. Each TLD has its own rules for which code points are allowed. If you search for "IDN allowed code points" you will find several projects that try to solve the problem. The scope of the code above is to encode and decode a string. Maintaining a list of which code points that are allowed for each TLD is another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Some's answer is absolutely awesome! Worked exactly how I was hoping for domains. However, I needed it to work for emails too. So I used Some's code and added a check for emails, then, with a little more logic, got it working for emails.
I am not a JavaScript dev by any streach of the imagination, but I can make stuff work when I need to.
This version will take domains or emails and convert to and from punycode.
(I also added semi-colons and brackets (for IFs). I know, not always necessary but it does make the code a little easier to read and also gets rid of the dammed red squigglies...) @some, I hope you approve =)

```
var punycode = new function Punycode() {
// punycode.ToASCII ( domain )
// punycode.ToUnicode (domain)
this.utf16 = {
    decode:function(input){
        var output = [], i=0, len=input.length,value,extra;
        while (i < len) {
            value = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            if ((value & 0xF800) === 0xD800) {
                extra = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                if ( ((value & 0xFC00) !== 0xD800) || ((extra & 0xFC00) !== 0xDC00) ) {
                    throw new RangeError("UTF-16(decode): Illegal UTF-16 sequence");
                }
                value = ((value & 0x3FF) << 10) + (extra & 0x3FF) + 0x10000;
            }
            output.push(value);
        }
        return output;
    },
    encode:function(input){
        var output = [], i=0, len=input.length,value;
        while (i < len) {
            value = input[i++];
            if ( (value & 0xF800) === 0xD800 ) {
                throw new RangeError("UTF-16(encode): Illegal UTF-16 value");
            }
            if (value > 0xFFFF) {
                value -= 0x10000;
                output.push(String.fromCharCode(((value >>>10) & 0x3FF) | 0xD800));
                value = 0xDC00 | (value & 0x3FF);
            }
            output.push(String.fromCharCode(value));
        }
        return output.join("");
    }
}
var initial_n = 0x80;
var initial_bias = 72;
var delimiter = "\x2D";
var base = 36;
var damp = 700;
var tmin=1;
var tmax=26;
var skew=38;
var maxint = 0x7FFFFFFF;
function decode_digit(cp) {
    return cp - 48 < 10 ? cp - 22 : cp - 65 < 26 ? cp - 65 : cp - 97 < 26 ? cp - 97 : base;
}
function encode_digit(d, flag) {
    return d + 22 + 75 * (d < 26) - ((flag !== 0) << 5);
}
function adapt(delta, numpoints, firsttime ) {
    var k;
    delta = firsttime ? Math.floor(delta / damp) : (delta >> 1);
    delta += Math.floor(delta / numpoints);
    for (k = 0; delta > (((base - tmin) * tmax) >> 1); k += base) {
            delta = Math.floor(delta / ( base - tmin ));
    }
    return Math.floor(k + (base - tmin + 1) * delta / (delta + skew));
}
function encode_basic(bcp, flag) {
    bcp -= (bcp - 97 < 26) << 5;
    return bcp + ((!flag && (bcp - 65 < 26)) << 5);
}
this.decode=function(input,preserveCase) {
    var output=[];
    var case_flags=[];
    var input_length = input.length;
    var n, out, i, bias, basic, j, ic, oldi, w, k, digit, t, len;
    n = initial_n;
    i = 0;
    bias = initial_bias;
    basic = input.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
    if (basic < 0) {basic = 0;}
    for (j = 0; j < basic; ++j) {
        if(preserveCase) {case_flags[output.length] = ( input.charCodeAt(j) -65 < 26);}
        if ( input.charCodeAt(j) >= 0x80) {
            throw new RangeError("Illegal input >= 0x80");
        }
        output.push( input.charCodeAt(j) );
    }
    for (ic = basic > 0 ? basic + 1 : 0; ic < input_length; ) {
        for (oldi = i, w = 1, k = base; ; k += base) {
                if (ic >= input_length) {
                    throw RangeError ("punycode_bad_input(1)");
                }
                digit = decode_digit(input.charCodeAt(ic++));
                if (digit >= base) {
                    throw RangeError("punycode_bad_input(2)");
                }
                if (digit > Math.floor((maxint - i) / w)) {
                    throw RangeError ("punycode_overflow(1)");
                }
                i += digit * w;
                t = k <= bias ? tmin : k >= bias + tmax ? tmax : k - bias;
                if (digit < t) { break; }
                if (w > Math.floor(maxint / (base - t))) {
                    throw RangeError("punycode_overflow(2)");
                }
                w *= (base - t);
        }
        out = output.length + 1;
        bias = adapt(i - oldi, out, oldi === 0);
        if ( Math.floor(i / out) > maxint - n) {
            throw RangeError("punycode_overflow(3)");
        }
        n += Math.floor( i / out ) ;
        i %= out;
        if (preserveCase) { case_flags.splice(i, 0, input.charCodeAt(ic -1) -65 < 26);}
        output.splice(i, 0, n);
        i++;
    }
    if (preserveCase) {
        for (i = 0, len = output.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (case_flags[i]) {
                output[i] = (String.fromCharCode(output[i]).toUpperCase()).charCodeAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return this.utf16.encode(output);
};
this.encode = function (input,preserveCase) {
    var n, delta, h, b, bias, j, m, q, k, t, ijv, case_flags;
    if (preserveCase) {
        case_flags = this.utf16.decode(input);
    }
    input = this.utf16.decode(input.toLowerCase());
    var input_length = input.length; // Cache the length
    if (preserveCase) {
        for (j=0; j < input_length; j++) {
            case_flags[j] = input[j] !== case_flags[j];
        }
    }
    var output=[];
    n = initial_n;
    delta = 0;
    bias = initial_bias;
    for (j = 0; j < input_length; ++j) {
        if ( input[j] < 0x80) {
            output.push(
                String.fromCharCode(
                    case_flags ? encode_basic(input[j], case_flags[j]) : input[j]
                )
            );
        }
    }
    h = b = output.length;
    if (b > 0) {output.push(delimiter);}
    while (h < input_length) {
        for (m = maxint, j = 0; j < input_length; ++j) {
            ijv = input[j];
            if (ijv >= n && ijv < m) {m = ijv;}
        }
        if (m - n > Math.floor((maxint - delta) / (h + 1))) {
            throw RangeError("punycode_overflow (1)");
        }
        delta += (m - n) * (h + 1);
        n = m;
        for (j = 0; j < input_length; ++j) {
            ijv = input[j];
            if (ijv < n ) {
                if (++delta > maxint) {return Error("punycode_overflow(2)");}
            }
            if (ijv === n) {
                for (q = delta, k = base; ; k += base) {
                    t = k <= bias ? tmin : k >= bias + tmax ? tmax : k - bias;
                    if (q < t) {break;}
                    output.push( String.fromCharCode(encode_digit(t + (q - t) % (base - t), 0)) );
                    q = Math.floor( (q - t) / (base - t) );
                }
                output.push( String.fromCharCode(encode_digit(q, preserveCase && case_flags[j] ? 1:0 )));
                bias = adapt(delta, h + 1, h === b);
                delta = 0;
                ++h;
            }
        }
        ++delta, ++n;
    }
    return output.join("");
};
function formatArray(arr){
    var outStr = "";
    if (arr.length === 1) {
        outStr = arr[0];
    } else if (arr.length === 2) {
        outStr = arr.join('.');
    } else if (arr.length > 2) {
        outStr = arr.slice(0, -1).join('@') + '.' + arr.slice(-1);
    }
    return outStr;
}
    this.ToASCII = function ( domain ) {
        try {
            var domain_array;
            if (domain.includes("@")) {
                domain_array = domain.split("@").join(".").split(".");
            }
            else {
                domain_array = domain.split(".");
            }
            var out = [];
            for (var i=0; i < domain_array.length; ++i) {
                var s = domain_array[i];
                out.push(
                    s.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/) ?
                    "xn--" + punycode.encode(s) :
                    s
                );
            }
            return formatArray(out)
        } catch (error) {
            return (domain)
        }
    };
    this.ToUnicode = function ( domain ) {
        try {
            var domain_array;
            if (domain.includes("@")) {
                domain_array = domain.split("@").join(".").split(".");
            }
            else {
                domain_array = domain.split(".");
            }
            var out = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < domain_array.length; ++i) {
                var s = domain_array[i];

                    out.push(
                        s.match(/^xn--/) ?
                            punycode.decode(s.slice(4)) :
                            s
                    );

            }
            return formatArray(out)
        } catch (error) {
            return (domain)
        }
    };};
```