# Fast conversion of an array of unsigned integers to base64

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, base64

I have a VBArray in Javascript containing a long set of 8-bit unsigned integers, more than 1'000'000 entries usually.

I can easily transform it to a conventional array or Uint8Array, and my goal is to obtain its base64 representation.

I have tried [the methods here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710001/how-to-convert-uint8-array-to-base64-encoded-string), but running

```
var b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, _uint8Array));
```

throws an out of stack space exception.

The conversion in itself is not a problem, because I could write my own conversion method which does the following

```
create empty bit string
foreach value in the array
  get binary with toString(2)
  pad the binary to make it 8-bit
  add it to the bit string
```

Base64 conversion is then trivial.

Performance, as you can imagine, is rather poor. Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this to limit the number of arguments, thus reducing the required stack space:

```
var A = new Uint8Array(10000000), s = '';

// Encode at most 49152 bytes at a time
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i += 49152) {
    s += btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, A.subarray(i, i + 49152)));
}
```

You can change the number `49152` to anything that is both under the browser's limit and divisible by 3.

Comment: Nice, concise. The 'divisible by 3' part is a detail which would have troubled many, padding FTW