# Img src path with header params to pass

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I have an img tag in jsp page where the src path requires header parameters to pass to get the image. How can we achieve it?

Comment: If you posted some code, I'm sure I could steer you in the right direction (ideally the <img> tag as well as the function in the jsp page).

Comment: Why does the image require header parameters to work?

Comment: BTW, people complaining about the lack of code, I'm not sure it would be helpful given the question. At least not yet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, you'll need to make an ajax request that sets the headers. Then, you need to use some HTML5 APIs to convert binary data recieved to base64. Finally, set the image src with the `data:` protocol and your base64 data.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "yourpage.jsp", true);
oReq.setRequestHeader("Your-Header-Here", "Value");
// use multiple setRequestHeader calls to set multiple values
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
  var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
  if (arrayBuffer) {
    var u8 = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    var b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u8));
    var mimetype="image/png"; // or whatever your image mime type is
    document.getElementById("yourimageidhere").src="data:"+mimetype+";base64,"+b64encoded;
  }
};
oReq.send(null);
```

Sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

[How to convert uint8 Array to base64 Encoded String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710001/how-to-convert-uint8-array-to-base64-encoded-string)

Comment: The only performance impact I've noticed is when opening devtools (because the base64 data url can be big). However, since this answer the [blob api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) has become standard, so you can use that instead of data urls now for better performance.

Answer (score 46):

You can now use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Making_fetch_requests) to add your headers and then load the result into an `<img>`:

```
const src = 'https://api.mywebsite.com/profiles/123/avatar';
const options = {
  headers: {
    'Some-Header': '...'
  }
};

fetch(src, options)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
  imgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

Comment: Finally I found this! This works perfectly fine and fast. All other methods based on XMLHttpRequest or converting the bytes of image to Base64 to are too slow for my needs. Note that 'fetch()' perfectly sends parallel requests like a regular <img src="..."> does, while XMLHttpRequest is limited in parallelism and makes the images to wait in queue. Thanks so much!

Comment: The MDN docs says that you should also free the object URL using `URL.revokeObjectURL`

Answer (score 8):

You can't access to the header params with the img tag, you've got two solutions :

Use an Ajax request with the header param and load the image data

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,[CODE-OF-THE-IMAHE]">`

Use GET parameters with a token to replace the header for this functionality

`<img src="controller?token=[TOKEN]">`

Comment: Your idea about adding the token as a param was spot on.  Thanks!

Comment: Sending a token in the URL is bad practice.

Comment: As a url parameter should really be extremely last resort, it is bad practice as it can expose the token through browser history, referrer header etc

Answer (score 7):

You can use following ugly inline hack

```html
<img src onerror="fetch('https://picsum.photos/200',{headers: {hello:'World!'}}).then(r=>r.blob()).then(d=> this.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(d));" />
```

Comment: If the fetch fails wouldn't that lead to infinite onerror loop?

Comment: @DrorBar probably `onerror` handler is executed only if errors occurs during load image using path given in src attribute (but I don't check this deeply). Code inside  `onerror` not handle any future errors.

Comment: This code is using modern JavaScript features, so it may not work in older browsers. It is also worth noting that this approach may cause security concerns, as it allows executing arbitrary JavaScript code on an error event.