# Not able to view image object from AWS S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded one image 10 times to the AWS S3 using PHP SDK, and the image has a dimension (1000w x 4890h). After uploading them, when I tried to view some images i got the below error message instead of the real image,

> {"success":false,"error":{"code":411,"type":"viewport_too_large","info":"The
>   viewport you specified is too large. [max. dimensions: 5000x5000]"}}

All images have public access and given all required permission,

Is anyone get this type of error while accessing any object from AWS S3,

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to view/access this image? Are you putting the URL in a web browser? Are you doing it by code? (If with code, please edit your question and show us your code.)

Comment: Have you tried to specify the content length on the header of the requests? As far as I can see, the http status error 411 indicates the missing of that parameter: https://httpstatuses.com/411

Comment: @JohnRotensteinI am getting the same error message when i access image in either browser or code, And there is no special code written to view image in code, just put image URL in <img> tag only.

Comment: @Miguel i just put image URL in the <img> tag to view in the my page, I dont know how to pass header in image html tag. If you know pls guide me about it, Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: May be this answer can help you, even though does not look as straight forward as I would like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609946/img-src-path-with-header-params-to-pass