# JavaScript readAsBinaryString Function on E11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

In this page  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ if you scroll down to example "Example: Slicing a file. Try it!" you will see uses of **readAsBinaryString** API to read bytes of local files.

I've seen IE (My case its IE11) doesn't support **readAsBinaryString**.

Even this code mentioned in post [HTML5 File API read as text and binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary) breaks at **readAsBinaryString** in IE11.

I have seen some post in stack overflow, it suggests use of ReadAsArrayBuffer(). But it is also not working. It returns undefined.

My question is what are the options if I have to run it on IE11? Is it possible to write another IE compatible JS function which will do the JOB of readAsBinaryString().

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is my solution.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
reader.onload = function(e) {
  if (reader.result) reader.content = reader.result;
  var base64Data = btoa(reader.content);
  //...
}
//extend FileReader
if (!FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString) {
    FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString = function (fileData) {
       var binary = "";
       var pt = this;
       var reader = new FileReader();      
       reader.onload = function (e) {
           var bytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
           var length = bytes.byteLength;
           for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
               binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
           }
        //pt.result  - readonly so assign binary
        pt.content = binary;
        $(pt).trigger('onload');
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
    }
}
```

Comment: in the main code I was using `FileReader` this way: `var reader = new FileReader(); reader.onload = function (e) { var data = e.target.result; ..CODE HERE.. };  reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile)`. I needed to change `reader.onload` this way: `reader.onload = function (e) { if (!e) {var data = reader.content;} else {var data = e.target.result; } ..CODE HERE.. };`

Comment: @Naigel comment was very helpful with the change he wrote. combining Jacks code and Naigels worked for me

Comment: `$(pt).trigger('onload');` is it jQuery's trigger method? How to do dispatch this event without jQuery?

Answer (score 52):

I combine @Jack answer with my comment to show a complete working example.

In the `<head>` section I added this script to add `FileReader.readAsBinaryString` function in IE11

```
if (FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString === undefined) {
    FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString = function (fileData) {
        var binary = "";
        var pt = this;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
            var length = bytes.byteLength;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
            }
            //pt.result  - readonly so assign content to another property
            pt.content = binary;
            pt.onload(); // thanks to @Denis comment
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
    }
}
```

Then I needed to slightly modify my original script code because `target.result` has no value when using this fallback function.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    // ADDED CODE
    if (!e) {
        var data = reader.content;
    }
    else {
        var data = e.target.result;
    }

    // business code
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
```

Comment: `$(pt).trigger('onload');` is it jQuery's trigger method?
How to do dispatch this event without jQuery?

Comment: Jack + Naigel = Just saved my day

Comment: @Denis added your suggestion, it was the only code line requiring jQuery and was easy to change with vanilla JS.

Comment: @NachPD glad to help someone else, I've already wasted hours on that point, let's make them worthy ;)

Comment: Why not always use `e.target.result`? Is `!e` ever true?

Answer (score 9):

`FileReader.readAsBinaryString` is a non-standard function and has been deprecated.

`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer` should be used instead.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString)

Answer (score 7):

For IE 11 you can use this XHR trick:

```
function blobToBinaryStringIE11(blob) {
    var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open("get", blobURL);
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var binary = xhr.response;
        // do stuff
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

It's 20x faster than the `Uint8Array + fromCharCode` route and as fast as `readAsBinaryString`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

with:

```
reader.readAsText(blob);
```

it's works well in cross browser.

Comment: There are problems with this. Since the browser thinks its text and not binary it can cause errors for example in firefox I got invalid characters error.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the answers here and ended up making a few slight changes.

Instead of assigning to pt.content, my solution is to send a custom object to the prototype's onload, that receiver can specifically look for, I named this property msieContent so it will be very specific.

Also I used other accepted answer for converting Uint8Array to string in more robust way, you can see full details of it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713326/213050

## Polyfill

```js
if (FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString === undefined) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713326/213050
    function Uint8ToString(u8a: Uint8Array) {
        const CHUNK_SZ = 0x8000;
        let c = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < u8a.length; i += CHUNK_SZ) {
            c.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u8a.subarray(i, i + CHUNK_SZ)));
        }
        return c.join('');
    }
    FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString = function (fileData) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => this.onload({
            msieContent: Uint8ToString(new Uint8Array(<any>reader.result))
        });
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
    }
}
```

## Usage

```js
private _handleTextFile(file: File) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        // support for msie, see polyfills.ts
        const readResult: string = (<any>e).msieContent || <string>e.target.result;

    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```