# readAsBinaryString is not supported on IE

Tags: javascript, sapui5, filereader

I am trying to upload excel data on UI without request to server and it working fine on other browser but not working on IE as getting error " readAsBinaryString method is not supported "

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391207/javascript-readasbinarystring-function-on-e11

Comment: Don't ever use readAsBinaryString, you should read as arrayBuffer if you are working with binary