# How to convert unit8array hexadecimal string

Tags: javascript, hex

I just contact with javascript, there is a demand, that is, to convert unit8array hexadecimal string, and to convert hexadecimal string unit8array; In simple terms; Is unit8array and mutual transformation between hexadecimal string

Comment: Related (about base64 instead of hex): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710001/how-to-convert-uint8-array-to-base64-encoded-string

Comment: Do you mean *uint8* instead of "unit8"?

Comment: So there's a demand. Did you meet it? If not, why not - where is your problem? Show us the code you tried. What is your question?

Comment: var test_string = "abcdefghijklimnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890你好";
    var u8 = _stringToArrayBuffer(test_string);
    var zip_string = jz.gz.compress(u8);
    var _u8_string = _unit8arrayToString(zip_string);－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－
zip_string is after gzip compressed data, returns the uint8array; I want to put uint8array into hexadecimal string; Don't know how to turn; Is there a similar transformation function can provide?