# How to convert byte array to base64

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

In this post ([Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)) they take base64 and convert to a byte array.
I haven't been able to figure out how to convert byte array back in to base64 code.

I tried using `fromCharCode()` and `btoa()` but had no luck.

Any tips on how to do this?

EDIT:
Here is my code:

```
function decode_byteArray(result){
                var binary = '';
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(result);
                var len = bytes.byteLength;
                for (var i =0; i < len; i++){
                    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                }
                return window.btoa(binary);

}
```

This returns nothing when I try to print it out. The responseText from the XMLHTTPRequest does print out the byte array however.

Comment: Have you considered this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710001/how-to-convert-uint8-array-to-base64-encoded-string

Comment: here is an example [https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string)

Comment: Please show us your attempt, otherwise we cannot help you find the problem in your code

Comment: Ok I tried a method from a comment above and still nothing. I added the code above