# How much can I compress 400 characters made up of 40 different characters?

Tags: javascript, url, compression

I have a 400 character string made up of a variety of 40 possible characters. The 40 characters are `a-z A-N`. In this example I have:

`nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnunnnnnnnnnnnnuuunnnuxunnnnnnnnnnuxddnnnuxduuuuuunnnnuxddnnnuxddddddunnnnuxddnuuuxdddddduuuuuuxddnnnuxduuudducuccuxddnnnuxdunodduiuiiuxddnnnuxduoodducuccuxddnnnuxdddddduiuiiuxddnnnuxdddddducuccuxddnnnuxdddddduiuiiuxddnnnuxduuudducuccuxddnuuuxdunodduiuiiuxddnnnuxduoodducuccuxddnnnuxdddddduuuuuuxddnnnuxxxxxxxunnnnuxxxnnnnuuuuuuuunnnnnuuunnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn`

I need to have the compressed version be made out of URL-safe characters. I am using `a-z A-N` and `0-9 - . _ ~ ( ) ' ! * : @ . ;` to represent how many times characters in the original string repeat up to 23 times. If a character repeats more than 23 times, the character and numerical representation is added onto the prior compressed string.

After compressing, the resulting string is 246 characters:

`n;un-u1n1uxun8uxd0n1uxdu4n2uxd0n1uxd4un2uxd0nu1xd4u4xd0n1uxdu1d0ucuc0uxd0n1uxdunod0uiui0uxd0n1uxduo0d0ucuc0uxd0n1uxd4uiui0uxd0n1uxd4ucuc0uxd0n1uxd4uiui0uxd0n1uxdu1d0ucuc0uxd0nu1xdunod0uiui0uxd0n1uxduo0d0ucuc0uxd0n1uxd4u4xd0n1ux5un2ux1n2u6n3u1n;n(`

The Javascript function to compress the original string is:

```js
// 40 single URL-safe characters 
let singleCharList = [
"a",
"b",
"c",
"d",
"e",
"f",
"g",
"h",
"i",
"j",
"k",
"l",
"m",
"n",
"o",
"p",
"q",
"r",
"s",
"t",
"u",
"v",
"w",
"x",
"y",
"z",
"A",
"B",
"C",
"D",
"E",
"F",
"G",
"H",
"I",
"J",
"K",
"L",
"M",
"N",
]

// 23 single URL-safe characters for counting (0 is actually 1)
let singleCharCountList = [
"0",
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5",
"6",
"7",
"8",
"9",
"-",
".",
"_",
"~",
"(",
")",
"'",
"!",
"*",
":",
"@",
",",
";",
]

function compressString(stringToCompress) {
  var compressedString = ""
  var lastChar = ""
  var inARowCount = 0
  var maxInARowCount = singleCharCountList.length
  for (i = 0; i < stringToCompress.length + 1; ++i) {
let currentChar = stringToCompress.charAt(i)
if (currentChar === lastChar && inARowCount < maxInARowCount) {
  inARowCount += 1
} else {
  if (inARowCount > 0) {
    singleCharCount = singleCharCountList[inARowCount - 1]
    compressedString = compressedString + lastChar + singleCharCount
  } else {
    compressedString = compressedString + lastChar
  }
  inARowCount = 0
}
lastChar = currentChar
  }
  return compressedString
}

// To inflate the string back to its original 400 characters, I have: 

function inflateString(stringToInflate) {
  var inflatedString = ""
  var lastChar = ""
  for (i = 0; i < stringToInflate.length; ++i) {
let currentChar = stringToInflate.charAt(i)
// currentChar is part of singleCharCountList 
// and lastChar is part of singleCharList
if (singleCharCountList.indexOf(currentChar) > -1 &&
  singleCharList.indexOf(lastChar) > -1) {
  var loop = singleCharCountList.indexOf(currentChar) + 1
  for (var j = 0; j < loop; ++j) {
    inflatedString = inflatedString + lastChar
  }
}
// currentChar is part of singleCharList
// and lastChar is part of singleCharCountList
else if (singleCharList.indexOf(currentChar) > -1 &&
  singleCharCountList.indexOf(lastChar) > -1) {
  inflatedString = inflatedString + currentChar
}
// currentChar is part of singleCharList
// and lastChar is part of singleCharList
else if (singleCharList.indexOf(currentChar) > -1 &&
  singleCharList.indexOf(lastChar) > -1) {
  inflatedString = inflatedString + currentChar
}
// current char is part of singleCharList
// and lastChar is not part of singleCharList or singleCharCountList
else if (singleCharList.indexOf(currentChar) > -1 &&
  singleCharList.indexOf(lastChar) == -1 &&
  singleCharCountList.indexOf(lastChar) == -1) {
  inflatedString = inflatedString + currentChar
}
lastChar = currentChar
  }
  return inflatedString
}


const str = 'nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnunnnnnnnnnnnnuuunnnuxunnnnnnnnnnuxddnnnuxduuuuuunnnnuxddnnnuxddddddunnnnuxddnuuuxdddddduuuuuuxddnnnuxduuudducuccuxddnnnuxdunodduiuiiuxddnnnuxduoodducuccuxddnnnuxdddddduiuiiuxddnnnuxdddddducuccuxddnnnuxdddddduiuiiuxddnnnuxduuudducuccuxddnuuuxdunodduiuiiuxddnnnuxduoodducuccuxddnnnuxdddddduuuuuuxddnnnuxxxxxxxunnnnuxxxnnnnuuuuuuuunnnnnuuunnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn';

const compressed = compressString(str);
console.log(compressed.length);
const inflate = inflateString(compressed)
console.log(str.length,inflateString.length)
```

Can I do better? I'm moderately happy with 246 in my example, but this can vary a lot depending on the original content.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to define some arrays and had an unnecessary function. Should run now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compress the string using a standard compression tool, such as zlib. Your example compresses from 400 bytes down to 93 with zlib. Then encode the binary result into your restricted set of 75 characters, which will expand it by about 30%, resulting in about 120 bytes. Still significantly compressed from the original 400.

That encoding can be done many ways, but the fastest is likely reverse Huffman coding, where you take the binary to represent a sequence of Huffman codes of a flat probability distribution of 75 symbols. You end up with 53 6-bit codes and 22 7-bit codes. That gives 6.29 bits per symbol, close to the optimal 6.23 bits per symbol.

It is a waste of time to develop your own, substandard, compression method with a weak attempt at run-length coding.

Comment: Can I compress it into a set of characters that are URL safe? This is one of my requirements.

Comment: Yes, by doing what I said in the answer. Please read the answer.

Comment: I'm using pako, and having trouble with this. I can see I get an array of up to 3-digit numbers if I deflate an array of my string. The length is 137, but how do I encode that into single characters? How do I know if I even have enough URI-safe characters to encode it?

Comment: There are 66 URI-safe characters: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.3 .

Comment: You can pick 64 of those to encode 6 bits of your data at a time. Take three of your byte, which are eight bits each and break it up into four groups of six bits. Encode a character of your set to put four characters into the URL.

Comment: I decided to use this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36046727/586006

It was a Uint8array from Pako. I encoded it into b64, which results in 184 characters. A worthwhile improvement! Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working for me since it uses spaces and forward slashes.

Comment: Just write it yourself.

Comment: I did, and it looks like my original RLE beats it every time.

Comment: Never mind I was deflating my array, and not a string version of that.