# How to convert a large uint8 Array to base64 encoded string

Tags: javascript, base64, buffer, typed-arrays

This differs from [caio keto's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12710001) as I'm dealing with large arrays and none of the proposed solutions for his question works for me.
I'm trying to convert a very large uin8array to base64 like this:

```
const encodedString = Buffer.from(veryLargeArray.buffer).toString("base64");
```

For smaller arrays this works fine, but for the larger ones the code block runs for 5-7 seconds and then crashes. I've tried, among other solutions, using [this byte-base64](https://gist.github.com/enepomnyaschih/72c423f727d395eeaa09697058238727) function as well as a chunk splitting solution proposed by chatgpt, but it still crashes:

[image]

Any idea how I might solve this issue?

Comment: how large is the array?

Comment: The large one is 87,031,808, the smaller one (that works) is 13,893,632

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58743798/11937654 it seems that the upper limit for working with arrays is around 30-50 million, even if the max length is 4 billion.