# How to url-encode UInt8Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, urlencode, uint8array

How can I urlencode a [UInt8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) in JavaScript? using encodeURIComponent does not work, for example with

```
encodeURIComponent((new Uint8Array([72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100])));
```

I expected:

```
Hello%20World
```

but I got

```
72%2C101%2C108%2C108%2C111%2C32%2C87%2C111%2C114%2C108%2C100"
```

Comment: *"I expected: `Hello%20World`"* What text encoding is the data in the array in? Apparently an 8-bit encoding, but which one? Your example uses characters that are the same in basically all of them, but in the general case there's a big difference between ASCII (limited range), UTF-8, Windows-1252, ISO 8859-1, ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's arbitrary binary data, from a `<input type="file">` - see https://serveurl.loltek.net/

Comment: Well, then it's not text, it's binary data. The only way to turn it in to *text* in a valid way is to treat that binary data in a way that correctly interprets it as text. More: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ If the receiving end is going to treat it as binary data, I guess you could just choose an encoding. But if it's going to treat it as *text*, then you'll get garbage for non-trivial cases.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know of any native function to do it, wrote a custom encoder, it should be binary-safe:

```js
function urlencode(str) {
    if (str instanceof Uint8Array) {
        let ret = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
            const c = str[i];
            if (
                (c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39) // 0-9
                || (c >= 0x41 && c <= 0x5A) // A-Z
                || (c >= 0x61 && c <= 0x7A) // a-z
            ) {
                ret += String.fromCharCode(c);
            } else {
                ret += "%" + c.toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    return encodeURIComponent(str);
}
```

and doing

```
urlencode((new Uint8Array([72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100])))
```

gives the expected

```
"Hello%20World"
```

... However testing shows that a lookup table is much faster:

```js
function urlencode(str) {
    if (str instanceof Uint8Array) {
        const table = ["%00", "%01", "%02", "%03", "%04", "%05", "%06", "%07", "%08", "%09", "%0A", "%0B", "%0C", "%0D", "%0E", "%0F", "%10", "%11", "%12", "%13", "%14", "%15", "%16", "%17", "%18", "%19", "%1A", "%1B", "%1C", "%1D", "%1E", "%1F", "%20", "%21", "%22", "%23", "%24", "%25", "%26", "%27", "%28", "%29", "%2A", "%2B", "%2C", "%2D", "%2E", "%2F", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "%3A", "%3B", "%3C", "%3D", "%3E", "%3F", "%40", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "%5B", "%5C", "%5D", "%5E", "%5F", "%60", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "%7B", "%7C", "%7D", "%7E", "%7F", "%80", "%81", "%82", "%83", "%84", "%85", "%86", "%87", "%88", "%89", "%8A", "%8B", "%8C", "%8D", "%8E", "%8F", "%90", "%91", "%92", "%93", "%94", "%95", "%96", "%97", "%98", "%99", "%9A", "%9B", "%9C", "%9D", "%9E", "%9F", "%A0", "%A1", "%A2", "%A3", "%A4", "%A5", "%A6", "%A7", "%A8", "%A9", "%AA", "%AB", "%AC", "%AD", "%AE", "%AF", "%B0", "%B1", "%B2", "%B3", "%B4", "%B5", "%B6", "%B7", "%B8", "%B9", "%BA", "%BB", "%BC", "%BD", "%BE", "%BF", "%C0", "%C1", "%C2", "%C3", "%C4", "%C5", "%C6", "%C7", "%C8", "%C9", "%CA", "%CB", "%CC", "%CD", "%CE", "%CF", "%D0", "%D1", "%D2", "%D3", "%D4", "%D5", "%D6", "%D7", "%D8", "%D9", "%DA", "%DB", "%DC", "%DD", "%DE", "%DF", "%E0", "%E1", "%E2", "%E3", "%E4", "%E5", "%E6", "%E7", "%E8", "%E9", "%EA", "%EB", "%EC", "%ED", "%EE", "%EF", "%F0", "%F1", "%F2", "%F3", "%F4", "%F5", "%F6", "%F7", "%F8", "%F9", "%FA", "%FB", "%FC", "%FD", "%FE", "%FF"];
        let ret = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
            ret += table[str[i]];
        }
        return ret;
    }
    return encodeURIComponent(str);
}
```

- using the benchmark code:

```js
function urlencode(str) {
    if (str instanceof Uint8Array) {
        let ret = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
            const c = str[i];
            if (
                (c >= 0x30 && c <= 0x39) // 0-9
                || (c >= 0x41 && c <= 0x5A) // A-Z
                || (c >= 0x61 && c <= 0x7A) // a-z
            ) {
                ret += String.fromCharCode(c);
            } else {
                ret += "%" + c.toString(16).padStart(2, "0");
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    return encodeURIComponent(str);
}
function urlencode2(str) {
    if (str instanceof Uint8Array) {
        const table = ["%00", "%01", "%02", "%03", "%04", "%05", "%06", "%07", "%08", "%09", "%0A", "%0B", "%0C", "%0D", "%0E", "%0F", "%10", "%11", "%12", "%13", "%14", "%15", "%16", "%17", "%18", "%19", "%1A", "%1B", "%1C", "%1D", "%1E", "%1F", "%20", "%21", "%22", "%23", "%24", "%25", "%26", "%27", "%28", "%29", "%2A", "%2B", "%2C", "%2D", "%2E", "%2F", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "%3A", "%3B", "%3C", "%3D", "%3E", "%3F", "%40", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "%5B", "%5C", "%5D", "%5E", "%5F", "%60", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "%7B", "%7C", "%7D", "%7E", "%7F", "%80", "%81", "%82", "%83", "%84", "%85", "%86", "%87", "%88", "%89", "%8A", "%8B", "%8C", "%8D", "%8E", "%8F", "%90", "%91", "%92", "%93", "%94", "%95", "%96", "%97", "%98", "%99", "%9A", "%9B", "%9C", "%9D", "%9E", "%9F", "%A0", "%A1", "%A2", "%A3", "%A4", "%A5", "%A6", "%A7", "%A8", "%A9", "%AA", "%AB", "%AC", "%AD", "%AE", "%AF", "%B0", "%B1", "%B2", "%B3", "%B4", "%B5", "%B6", "%B7", "%B8", "%B9", "%BA", "%BB", "%BC", "%BD", "%BE", "%BF", "%C0", "%C1", "%C2", "%C3", "%C4", "%C5", "%C6", "%C7", "%C8", "%C9", "%CA", "%CB", "%CC", "%CD", "%CE", "%CF", "%D0", "%D1", "%D2", "%D3", "%D4", "%D5", "%D6", "%D7", "%D8", "%D9", "%DA", "%DB", "%DC", "%DD", "%DE", "%DF", "%E0", "%E1", "%E2", "%E3", "%E4", "%E5", "%E6", "%E7", "%E8", "%E9", "%EA", "%EB", "%EC", "%ED", "%EE", "%EF", "%F0", "%F1", "%F2", "%F3", "%F4", "%F5", "%F6", "%F7", "%F8", "%F9", "%FA", "%FB", "%FC", "%FD", "%FE", "%FF"];
        let ret = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
            ret += table[str[i]];
        }
        return ret;
    }
    return encodeURIComponent(str);
}
function generateRandomUint8Array(length) {
    // crypto.getRandomValues() is limited to 65535 bytes per call so we need to call it multiple times
    let ret = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length;) {
        let arr = new Uint8Array(Math.min(65535, length - i));
        crypto.getRandomValues(arr);
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; ++j) {
            ret.push(arr[j]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return new Uint8Array(ret);
}
test10MB = generateRandomUint8Array(10 * 1024 * 1024);
t1 = Date.now(); garbage = urlencode(test10MB); t2 = Date.now(); console.log(t2 - t1);
t1 = Date.now(); garbage = urlencode(test10MB); t2 = Date.now(); console.log(t2 - t1);
t1 = Date.now(); garbage = urlencode2(test10MB); t2 = Date.now(); console.log(t2 - t1);
t1 = Date.now(); garbage = urlencode2(test10MB); t2 = Date.now(); console.log(t2 - t1);
```

urlencode() use about 2000 milliseconds on 10MB, and urlencode2() use about 800 milliseconds on 10MB, a lookup table more-than-doubles the performance on Edge!

And on Firefox the results are even better (in all cases, for some reason..) urlencode() use about 500 milliseconds and urlencode2() use about 61 milliseconds, a lookup table is 8 times faster on Firefox!

.. I guess function call overhead is to blame?

Comment: (You should probably use this solution anyway; it’s robust and clear.)

Comment: @Ry- any comment on the lookup table approach? twice as fast on Edge and 8 times faster on Firefox?

Comment: Yep, that’s a good approach. (Honestly, I’m surprised it’s such a bottleneck at just 10 MB.)

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn’t feel very nice, but you can make a string out of any bytes, which `escape` will then URL-encode as Latin-1 (i.e. bytes):

```js
const bytes = new Uint8Array([72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100]);

console.log(escape(String.fromCharCode(...bytes)));
```

Comment: escape is depricated

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev: And yet it’s the only correct option when using this bytes-via-string path.

Comment: then TextDecoder like T.J. Crowder suggested

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev: As specified in the comment on the question, the input is arbitrary bytes, not necessarily UTF-8. The original self-answer is a good choice though.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev T.J.'s approach is not binary safe (see my comment to his answer)

Comment: I bet if we benchmark it, your solution should be faster than every other binary-safe solution posted here :) and shorter

Comment: On a 50KB PNG image, your approach use about 1ms while my approach use about 5ms - your approach is 5 times faster than mine, in a crude test :)

Comment: found 1 issue, this approach doesn't handle [47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_47) correctly, ```bytes = new Uint8Array([47]);console.log(escape(String.fromCharCode(...bytes)));``` expected `%2F` but got `/`

Comment: wonder if it can be fixed with ```console.log(escape(String.fromCharCode(...bytes)).replace(/\//g,"%2F"));``` ?

Comment: @hanshenrik: Mm, good point. Is that a problem for your website, though? (`+` probably is either way.) I’d still recommend your answer. Note that `String.fromCharCode(...bytes)` can also fail with a RangeError (too many arguments) if `bytes` is long enough, so at a certain point all the fixes become more complicated than they’re worth.

Answer (score 1):

If it's **text** (as it seemed in the question), I'd use [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) with the text encoding the data in the array is in. For instance, using the default UTF-8:

```
const encoded = encodeURIComponent(new TextDecoder().decode(array));
```

Live Example:

```js
const array = new Uint8Array([72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100]);

const encoded = encodeURIComponent(new TextDecoder().decode(array));
console.log(encoded);
```

---

But in a comment you've said it's just arbitrary binary data. In that case, I'd send it using Base-64 encoding or similar, rather than as text. You'd do that as shown in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710001/how-to-convert-uint8-array-to-base64-encoded-string). For instance, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66046176/) shows doing it with built-in browser features:

> ```
> // note: `buffer` arg can be an ArrayBuffer or a Uint8Array
> async function bufferToBase64(buffer) {
>   // use a FileReader to generate a base64 data URI:
>   const base64url = await new Promise(r => {
>     const reader = new FileReader()
>     reader.onload = () => r(reader.result)
>     reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([buffer]))
>   });
>   // remove the `data:...;base64,` part from the start
>   return base64url.slice(base64url.indexOf(',') + 1);
> }
>
> // example use:
> await bufferToBase64(new Uint8Array([1,2,3,100,200]))
> ```

Live Example:

```html
<script type="module">
const array = new Uint8Array([72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100]);

const encoded = encodeURIComponent(await bufferToBase64(array));
console.log(encoded);

// From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66046176/
// note: `buffer` arg can be an ArrayBuffer or a Uint8Array
async function bufferToBase64(buffer) {
  // use a FileReader to generate a base64 data URI:
  const base64url = await new Promise(r => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = () => r(reader.result)
    reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([buffer]))
  });
  // remove the `data:...;base64,` part from the start
  return base64url.slice(base64url.indexOf(',') + 1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: this does not work with non-utf8-valid binary data, for example ```InvalidAsUTF8=new Uint8Array([252,161,161,161,161,161]) ; encodeURIComponent(new TextDecoder().decode(InvalidAsUTF8)); ``` returns ```%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD```, whatever that is,  not the expected ```%fc%a1%a1%a1%a1%a1``` 

Comment: @hanshenrik - That's why I said to use the encoding of the text (this was before you said it was arbitrary binary data), and why I suggested using Base-64 for arbitrary binary data, not text.

Answer (score -1):

You can converts the `Uint8Array` to a string before encoding it using `encodeURIComponent`.

```js
const uint8Array = new Uint8Array([72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100]);

// Convert Uint8Array to a regular array of characters
const charArray = Array.from(uint8Array, byte => String.fromCharCode(byte));

// Join the characters to form a string
const stringFromUint8 = charArray.join('');

// Encode the string using encodeURIComponent
const encodedString = encodeURIComponent(stringFromUint8);

console.log(encodedString); // Output: Hello%20World
```

Comment: Same comment on Alexander Nenashev’s answer applies to this one.

Comment: Warning, this approach is not binary-safe. With the input ```InvalidAsUTF8=new Uint8Array([252,161,161,161,161,161]) ;```, this approach generates ```%C3%BC%C2%A1%C2%A1%C2%A1%C2%A1%C2%A1```, whatever that is, not the expected ```%fc%a1%a1%a1%a1%a1```