# is it possible to get utf8arrary from blobstorage in client

Tags: javascript, azure-blob-storage

I use SAS to access files. 
So i can get the files’ content by send a request.

But the problem is that i need to change the file’s encoding to SJIS.

so i’m trying to use `Encoding.convert()`, according to this (https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js/blob/master/README_ja.md)

After this I’m going to use

```
URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([sjiscontent], {type: "text.plain"}))
```

But I don’t know how to convert my blobs’ string context to a sjis utf8arrary properly.

Comment: Yes you can. have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191945/conversion-between-utf-8-arraybuffer-and-string

Comment: I will try it. Is it the only way to do it? if the blob is large, will it take to much time?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Streaming APIs of [`iconv-lite`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) and [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) node packages to convert the content encoding in a stream.

For example, you have a blob url with SAS token.

```
var request = require('request');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
request('<a blob url with sas token>')
    .pipe(iconv.decodeStream('UTF-8'))
    .pipe(iconv.encodeStream('shift_jis'))
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('<your local file path>'))
```

The `iconv-lite` package supports `Shift_JIS` (`SJIS`) encoding.

Comment: But I'm not using nodejs. How could I use by javascript?