# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 Error in JS

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, arraybuffer

when i execute this

```
JSON.parse(ArrayBuffer);
```

I have this Error :
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0`

Thanks for you response

Comment: Arraybuffer is binary data.  Json is a text serializer

Comment: Thank for you response, i can know if i can transform binary data to text serializer because i try to get `ArrayBuffer` to `UTF-8` to `JSON`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191945/conversion-between-utf-8-arraybuffer-and-string

Answer (score 0):

Is your question why the error is occurring? This error occurs when we pass an "undefined" value to the JSON.parse method. ArrayBuffer is a binary data type. JSON.parse expects a JSON object to work properly.