# How to get encoded data in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I prepared the below CSharp code  and I want to send that encoded data to js file where i want original data...
Is it possible to decode it on js page
Problem: the byte array send by csharp file is not decoded at js

```
 UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        String unicodeString = "ABCD";
        // Encode the string.
        Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);
```

Comment: Have you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356493/decode-utf-8-with-javascript

Comment: @wojjas Yes, but it's something different and my doubt is something differenct

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Create Base64 Object
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

// Define the string
var string = 'Hello World!';

// Encode the String
var encodedString = Base64.encode(string);
console.log(encodedString); // Outputs: "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"

// Decode the String
var decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString); // Outputs: "Hello World!"
```

**Reply of comment**

Use this in c# to encode

```
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
var encodedString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

And decode in javascript decode like this

```
  var decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString);
    console.log(decodedString);
```

[**Reference for decoding in javascript**](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/qAGHT)

Comment: I don't want to use BASE64. Problem is I have Csharp code in UTF-8 format and i want to send it to Javascirpt file and decode there only

Comment: Where are you using `this c#/javascript`? @rakeshgupta

Comment: C sharp file or asp file
having the code:
 UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
String unicodeString = "µ";
// Encode the string.
Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);
"now i am sending unicodestring to js"

facing problem in js, not able to decode it

Comment: Sorry Manoj but code is not working,Reason is two times encoding.
Ex: plaintext = "A" then first it convert into utf which is "65" then 65 is converted  into Base64 which is qq== someting. 
on other side decoding also not working

Comment: In `c#` you have successfully encoded and decode in javascript here is a reference http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/qAGHT/ @rakeshgupta