# Correcting incorrectly encoded string (ASCII characters back to UTF-8)

Tags: javascript, android, encoding, wifi, ssid

Here is a sample WiFi ssid I have extracted from an Android "wifi config file" (`wpa_supplicant.conf`).

I'm trying to display all the ssid's in the file, most are okay as they are normal strings wrapped in quotes, for example,

```
network={
    ssid="Linksys"
    ...
}
```

However, some entries just wanted to be different and special, for example,

```
network={
    ssid=e299aa20e6b7a1e5ae9ae69c89e98ca2e589a920e299ab
    ...
}
```

Now, the question is, how do I convert it back to a readable string (preferably in JS)? I suspect the encoding was wrong (it displays correctly on a native device though.)

Comment: Is that a real example? Because it seems to be gibberish when interpreted as ASCII or UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: That is a real example. I passed it (manually turned it into binary) through a UTF 8 decoder and it does return the correct string.

Comment: @m69 `♪ 淡定有錢剩 ♫` This is the correct string

Comment: Q: How to decode UTF-8 with javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356493/decode-utf-8-with-javascript

Comment: @m69 Thanks for the link. However the answer in your link does not answer my question in any way. The second answer is related but only works for one character with predetermined grouping. Anyway, I have read through [how UTF8 works](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm) and implemented it in JS.

Comment: That turned out to be a lot more complicated than I was expecting :-)

Comment: @m69 There's definitely room for improvement such that it can be shorter and faster, but the current code I have is good enough for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the string is in hex unencoded. By turning it back to binary following by some string manipulation, I am able to encode it back to the readable form.

```
function HextoUTF8(txt) {
    function HexStringToBytes(str) {
        if (str.length % 2) throw TypeError("Not a valid length");

        return [].map.call(str, function(e) {
            return ("000" + parseInt(e, 16).toString(2)).slice(-4);
        }).join("").match(/.{8}/g);
    }

    function BytesToUTF8(bytes) {
        var inExpectationMode = false,
            itr = new Iterator(bytes),
            byte,
            availableBitsTable = {
                "1": -7,
                "2": -5,
                "3": -4,
                "4": -3
            },
            expectingBitsLeft = 0,
            currectCharacter = "",
            result = "";

        while (byte = itr.next(), !byte.ended) {
            byte = byte.value;

            if (inExpectationMode) {
                currectCharacter += byte.slice(-6);
            } else {
                //First in sequence
                expectingBitsLeft = determineSequenceLength(byte);
                currectCharacter += byte.slice(availableBitsTable[expectingBitsLeft]);
            }

            inExpectationMode = true;
            expectingBitsLeft--;

            if (!expectingBitsLeft) {
                inExpectationMode = false;
                result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(currectCharacter, 2));
                currectCharacter = "";
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    function determineSequenceLength(byte) {
        if (byte[0] === "0") return 1;
        else if (byte.slice(0, 3) === "110") return 2;
        else if (byte.slice(0, 4) === "1110") return 3;
        else if (byte.slice(0, 5) === "11110") return 4;
    }

    function Iterator(array) {
        if (this === window) throw TypeError("This is a class");
        if (!Array.isArray(array)) throw TypeError("An array is required");

        this.i = -1;
        this.ended = !array.length;
        this.array = function() {
            return array;
        };
    }

    Iterator.prototype.next = function() {
        if (this.ended || ++this.i == this.array().length) {
            this.ended = true;
            return {
                ended: true
            };
        } else {
            return {
                ended: this.ended,
                value: this.array()[this.i]
            };
        }
    }

    return BytesToUTF8(HexStringToBytes(txt));
}
```

Optimally I should be doing bit manipulation instead, but whatever, it works,

```
> HextoUTF8("e299aa20e6b7a1e5ae9ae69c89e98ca2e589a920e299ab");
> "♪ 淡定有錢剩 ♫"
```