# Alternatives to escape(string) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When changing to TypeScript I'm not allowed to use escape(string) anymore because it's [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp). The reason I still use it is that the alternatives encodeURI and encodeURIComponent give a different results.

```js
var s = "Å"
console.log(escape(s));
console.log(encodeURI(s));
console.log(encodeURIComponent(s));
```

I don't use this for URLs, but for a CSV export.

What are other alternatives that will give me the same result as `escape(string)`?

Comment: What is purpose of escaping string?

Comment: You can read [EcmaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) section 15.1.2.4 where you can find algorithm for escape and implment the function yourself.

Comment: Do you depend on another piece of software that requires this precise format? Because the reason the two results are so different is that they are based on two different string encodings, which means that you may have further problems down the line when loading the CSV file and that you have to choose something that is future-proof and can be easily decoded (And CSV is totally agnostic on that regard).

Comment: I use this for exporting a datatable (json) to CSV format and open it in Excel. The export contains Norwegian charachters (like æ,ø,å,Æ,Ø,Å) which don't render correct in Excel unless I use the escape(string) function...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [EcmaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) there is algorithm:

1. Call ToString(string).
2. Compute the number of characters in Result(1).
3. Let R be the empty string.
4. Let k be 0.
5. If k equals Result(2), return R.
6. Get the character at position k within Result(1).
7. If Result(6) is one of the 69 nonblank ASCII characters ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 0123456789 @*_+-./, go to step 14.
8. Compute the 16-bit unsigned integer that is the Unicode character encoding of Result(6).
9. If Result(8), is less than 256, go to step 12.
10. Let S be a string containing six characters “%uwxyz” where wxyz are four hexadecimal digits encoding the
    value of Result(8).
11. Go to step 15.
12. Let S be a string containing three characters “%xy” where xy are two hexadecimal digits encoding the
    value of Result(8).
13. Go to step 15.
14. Let S be a string containing the single character Result(6).
15. Let R be a new string value computed by concatenating the previous value of R and S.
16. Increase k by 1.
17. Go to step 5.

which can be coded like this:

```
(function(global) {
    var allowed = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@*_+-./,';
    global.escapeString = function(str) {
        str = str.toString();
        var len = str.length, R = '', k = 0, S, chr, ord;
        while(k < len) {
            chr = str[k];
            if (allowed.indexOf(chr) != -1) {
                S = chr;
            } else {
                ord = str.charCodeAt(k);
                if (ord < 256) {
                    S = '%' + ("00" + ord.toString(16)).toUpperCase().slice(-2);
                } else {
                    S = '%u' + ("0000" + ord.toString(16)).toUpperCase().slice(-4);
                }
            }
            R += S;
            k++;
        }
        return R;
    };

})(typeof window == 'undefined' ? global : window);
```