# How to properly decode and unescape text in Node and the browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, character-encoding, escaping

I am parsing a binary file to extract the text. It mostly works, however certain letters that should be accented have a garbled encoding.  For example I get `SeÃ±or` instead of `Señor`, or `salvaciÃ³n` instead of `salvación`.

My library needs to work in **both** a Node and a web browser environment.

Currently this is working for me in a Node environment only, but I do not know how to replicate this behavior in a browser since I cannot import `querystring` there

```ts
import { unescape } from 'querystring';

export class CharHelpers {
  cleanString(str: string): string {
    //decode character to UTF-8. Helps with accented characters.
    //This converts things like 'salvaciÃ³n' to 'salvación'
    return (
      unescape(this.escapeString(str))
        //Replace CRLF with a single \n
        .replace(/\r\n/g, '\n')
        //remove any trailing whitespace or newlines
        .trim()
    );
  }

  private escapeString(str: string): string {
    //A replacement for the deprecated escape method
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303214/79677
    const allowed = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@*_+-./,';
    str = str.toString();
    const len = str.length;
    let R = '';
    let k = 0;
    let S = '';
    let chr = '';
    let ord = 0;
    while (k < len) {
      chr = str[k];
      if (allowed.indexOf(chr) !== -1) {
        S = chr;
      } else {
        ord = str.charCodeAt(k);
        if (ord < 256) {
          S = '%' + ('00' + ord.toString(16)).toUpperCase().slice(-2);
        } else {
          S = '%u' + ('0000' + ord.toString(16)).toUpperCase().slice(-4);
        }
      }
      R += S;
      k++;
    }
    return R;
  }
}
```

See the below demo that the following do not work completely.  I can convert either the accented characters OR the otherwise encoded characters, but not both. Also I sometimes run into strange characters in my library that would cause the `URI` methods to throw an error

```js
function escapeString(str) {
  //A replacement for the deprecated escape method
  //https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303214/79677
  const allowed = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@*_+-./,';
  str = str.toString();
  const len = str.length;
  let R = '';
  let k = 0;
  let S = '';
  let chr = '';
  let ord = 0;
  while (k < len) {
    chr = str[k];
    if (allowed.indexOf(chr) !== -1) {
      S = chr;
    } else {
      ord = str.charCodeAt(k);
      if (ord < 256) {
        S = '%' + ('00' + ord.toString(16)).toUpperCase().slice(-2);
      } else {
        S = '%u' + ('0000' + ord.toString(16)).toUpperCase().slice(-4);
      }
    }
    R += S;
    k++;
  }
  return R;
}

function tryParse(method, s){
  try{
    console.log(method.name , ' -> ', method(s));
  } catch(ex){
    console.error(method.name , ' -> ', ex.message)
  }
}

//-------------------------------

const str = 'SeÃ±or and salvaciÃ³n and Number%3A 1234%3B %06%88';
//Expecting: 'Señor and salvación and Number: 1234; ♠'

tryParse(unescape, str); //converts : and ; but not accented chars
tryParse(unescape, escapeString(str)); //converts nothing
tryParse(decodeURI, str); //Malformed URI error
tryParse(decodeURIComponent, str); //Malformed URI error
tryParse(decodeURI, escapeString(str)); //converts accented chars but not : and ;
tryParse(decodeURIComponent, escapeString(str)); //converts accented chars but not : and ;
```

None of these issues happen in the first code block in my question when run in Node, but that relies on something which I cannot use in a browser. How can I reliably convert these strings in **both** Node and a browser?

Comment: Debugging someone elses code with single letter variables in a non trivial task...

Comment: I agree, and I'm not opposed to throwing that away and using something else that might work better. I just haven't found anything yet. Really I don't think that function is the problem though