# Store JSON Object in Cookie

Tags: javascript, java, json, cookies

I would like to store a JSON Object in Cookie. Since version 0 cookie values are restrictive in allowed characters, it only allows url safe characters. That's why I encoded it in UTF-8. After encoding it, JSON characters are changed.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("res", URLEncoder.encode(res, "UTF-8"));
    cookie.setComment("comment");
    cookie.setMaxAge(24*60*60);
    cookie.setPath("/t/res");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
```

JSON:

```
{
"evt": [{
    "id": "2",
    "qty": "2"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "qty": "7"
}],
"exc": [{
    "id": "2",
    "qty": "3"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "qty": "6"
}],
"qt": "15",
"ti": "067e61623b6f4ae2a1712470b63dff00",
"rm": {
    "aci": "6",
    "rt": "5"
    }
}
```

This is how it is shown in cookie:

```
%7B%22evt%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22exc%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22qt%22%3A%221%22%2C%22ti%22%3A%22067e61623b6f4ae2a1712470b63dff00%22%2C%22rm%22%3A%7B%22aci%22%3A%226%22%2C%22rt%22%3A%225%22%7D%7D
```

I parse it in JS `JSON.parse(jsn)`, I get an error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Am I missing something or how exactly can I parse it?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use JSON.stringify(res) to make your object, this always seems pretty safe to me when encoding/decoding something I want to store, rather than using your URLEncoder here.

Comment: It just returns `{}`

Comment: Referring to answer below, think you might need to do what you're doing, but decode that url first, then JSON.parse it

Answer (score 0):

After encoding uri, you also eed to decode it before parsing.
var x= java.net.URLDecoder.decode(jsn, "UTF-8"); 
Use JSON.parse(x) instead of JSON.parse alone
If this isn't answer look at this
[Decode UTF-8 with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356493/decode-utf-8-with-javascript)

Comment: I got an error ` Unexpected token % in JSON at position 6`

Comment: along with above use encodeURI(res) instead of URLEncoder.encode(res, "UTF-8")

Comment: Do I need to change `URLEncoder.encode(res, "UTF-8")` to `encodeURI(res)` in java code? I didn't understand well.