# Angular HttpClient response is different from navigator preview, special characters are not decoded

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am having problems with a json response containing special characters.
In my code I have request like this:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
this.HttpClent.get<any>(my_url, {headers})
    .subsrcibe(res => console.log(res));
```

If I look at the preview in my navigator (Firefox or Chrome give the same result) I have this:

[image]

but the console.log give me this:

[image]

As you can see all the special characters, that were correctly displayed in the preview, are now broken in the object obtained from the response.

Any idea?

Comment: Is this only a problem in `console.log`, or is it a genuine problem elsewhere?

Comment: One possible cause is that the original file (data) is saved in the wrong encoding and not UTF-8, so the it has to be re-encoded.

Comment: @KurtHamilton the console.log is just to visualize it. If you look 'inside' the object in the debugger the strings are broken.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa. My understanding was that, if the encoding was wrong, the preview as well should be broken

Comment: @Alessandro_V: Not essentially, the string shown in preview was decoded by the browser whereas the decoding is not handled by HttpClient in Angular explicitly. See [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/175#issuecomment-405103945) for more info. Please check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13691499/6513921) answer solves the issue.

Comment: @MichaelD: thanks for the input. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to solve the issue.
`escape(decodeURIComponent(res[1].layer))` gives `"%uFFFDta"` that is actually the escaped replacement character

Comment: I believe it should be `decodeURIComponent(escape(res[1].layer))`.

Comment: Tested as well ;) It gives `"ï¿½ta"`