# Javascript analogue of Python's string.encode('UTF-8')

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I have a string that represents some binary data, looking like:
`\x89PNG\x1a\x00\x00\x00IHDR\x00\x00` etc

I need to post this string to some API, etc. AS IS but the problem is that Javascript automatically converts it to
`PNG` etc

.escape, .encodeURI.. etc don't help

In Python such conversion can be done like **string.encode('UTF-8')** but I can't find nothing like that in JS.

Maybe someone knows the library or something that may help?

Comment: How are you trying to upload it? It will need to be in a FormData, not a string.

Comment: `string.encode("UTF-8")` is for binary data that contains text. PNG data is not text, encoding it as UTF-8 is not correct.

Comment: @Barmar I do, the problem is that I need to add the encrypted signature to the Headers. The signature is generated from the whole data that I post, including the PNG.

That's why I need this string

Comment: Loop through the string calling `string.charCodeAt(i)` to get the numeric codes and calculate a signature.

Comment: "*I have a string that represents some binary data*" - why are you not using a typed array / arraybuffer? And is the string `"\\x89PNG\\x1a\\x00\\x00\\x00IHDR\\x00\\x00"` or does it really contain the bytes as characters `"\x89PNG\x1a\x00\x00\x00IHDR\x00\x00"`?

Comment: @Bergi just the strings, the question was how to turn it to something like the binary string

Comment: @ElRey777 did you find any solutions to this? I'm also trying to create a sign, but the options I have tried in JS give a different result from python's string.encode('UTF-8')

Comment: @Jumper no, unfortunately I couldn't so far... please share if you'll be more successful with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript we usualy use [Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) for this.

You can do something like

```
var encodedData = window.btoa(stringToEncode);
var decodedData = window.atob(encodedData);
```

You may also find this interesting

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

Or reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/22373061/6302200

Comment: Thanks! The reference has a lot of interesting sruff