# Is There a Snowflake Update SQL Statement to Decode UTF-8 Bytes?

Tags: sql, utf-8, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, decode

I have data in a Snowflake table column that looks like this...

```
These are actually Japanese characters \xe3\x81\xaa\xe3\x81\x9c\xe6\x97\xa5\xe9\x8a\x80\xe3\x81\xa0\xe3\x81\x91\xe9\x81\x95\xe3\x81\x86\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\x8b\xef\xbc\x9f
```

That is the complete value of one column

The UTF-8 decoded value of those characters above is なぜ日銀だけ違うのか？

Can someone suggest an update SQL statement that would change the value of the column to

```
These are actually Japanese characters なぜ日銀だけ違うのか？
```

Better still, is there an update statement that will decode any UTF-8 bytes to convert them into the desired characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick JS UDF solves the problem:

```sql
create or replace function decode_utf8(S string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
return decodeURIComponent(escape(S));
$$;
```

In action:

```sql
select decode_utf8('These are actually Japanese characters \xe3\x81\xaa\xe3\x81\x9c\xe6\x97\xa5\xe9\x8a\x80\xe3\x81\xa0\xe3\x81\x91\xe9\x81\x95\xe3\x81\x86\xe3\x81\xae\xe3\x81\x8b\xef\xbc\x9f ')
```

Screenshot as proof:

[image]

(based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13691499/132438)

Comment: This is great, and it works just as you show here. Thank you. I see however, that it works for string literals only. If I provide a column name, it seems to have no effect. For example SELECT TBL_COL, DECODE_UTF8(TBL_COL) AS TBL_COL_NEW FROM TBL, then TBL_COL _NEW has the same, unchanged value as TBL_COL in the result set. Is there a way to modify it to get the same effect?

Comment: Depends how the columns are encoded. Can you provide a new question that starts with INSERT statements, so I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Yes it works only for string literals not for columns