# How to convert binary data from binaryjs to string / text

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, converters

My BinaryJS webclient receives binary data, how do i convert it back to the text input which the server sent?

The Server (with NodeJS), which creates a Websocket, uses BinaryJS because it gets the data to transmit as a stream, and i wanted to forward that data to the client using Websocket streaming.

The web client looks the following:

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdn.binaryjs.com/0/binary.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="text-encoding/lib/encoding.js"></script>
    <script src="decode.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Connect to Binary.js server
      var client = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9000');
      // Received new stream from server!
      client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
        // Buffer for parts
        // Got new data
        stream.on('data', function(data){
          $( ".inner" ).append(data+"<br />");
        });
        stream.on('end', function(){
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="inner">Output:</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Sadly my output is not the input text but only something like this:

```
[object ArrayBuffer]
```

Edit: 
Found a possible solution:

As the data is UTF-8 encoded, i could simply decode it using a function someone posted in another question:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases here:

I assume you are referring to this question: [Uint8Array to string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936984/uint8array-to-string-in-javascript)

Note that the `fromCharCode` answer there explicitly says that it does not decode UTF8 properly. Your best bet would be to decode the ArrayBuffer using a FileReader. You are also incorrectly processing this content in the `data` handler, not you should be aggregating it first.

```
client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
    var parts = [];
    stream.on('data', function(data){
        parts.push(data);
    });
    stream.on('end', function(){
        var blob = new Blob(parts);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            $( ".inner" ).append(reader.result + "<br />");
        };
        reader.readAsText(blob);
    });
});
```

Now that said, my actual suggestion is that you not use `Binary.js` for this case. The whole point of it is to transfer binary data. If you are planning to transfer mostly text, you should look into using more text-oriented libraries like Socket.IO.