# ionic, how to change uint array to string (utf-8)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3

```
 uintToString(uintArray) {
var encodedString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uintArray),
    decodedString = decodeURIComponent(escape(encodedString));
return decodedString;
```

it works very well on ionic serve command!
but the problem is that when I command ionic cordova run android --device

**it comes error saying cannot find name 'escape'.**

how can I change uint array to utf -8 string... on ionic3?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936984/uint8array-to-string-in-javascript  please check this may hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

The global `escape` function [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape), you should use `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to turn `Uint8Array` into `string`:

```
static uint2str(array: Uint8Array): string {
  const chars: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    chars.push(String.fromCharCode(array[i]));
  }
  return chars.join('');
}
```