# How to get string from byte array generated by android.util Base64 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android

I receive a Uint8Array, the `data` is generated from `string` by android.util Base64 NO_WRAP:

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(string, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

I want to get the string from this data in my javascript application. I have tried use `btoa(string)` to generate the same data and use `atob(data)` to get string. But it doesn't work.

Can you give me a solution?

Thanks

Comment: This might contain your answer. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936984/uint8array-to-string-in-javascript)