# Query string  pass by $_GET method

Tags: php, javascript, string

I want to pass sValue that contain non-English String

```
  ....
 $.post("ajax.php?module=test&action=updates&id="+id+"&field="+field+"&val="+sValue;                                    
...
```

Then

```
$valUpdate = $_GET['val'];
$sQuery = " UPDATE $sTable SET  $colUpdate = '$valUpdate' WHERE  id = $id";
    $req = $pdo->prepare($sQuery);
    $req->execute();
    $req->closeCursor();
```

Anyone could told me ,How can I fix this ?

thanks

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834316/how-to-convert-large-utf-8-strings-into-ascii

Comment: You're using `$.post` with GET parameters. Just have to set POST parameters instead.

Comment: Technically he's passing them as GET parameters, on account of the ?...&

Comment: What's the point of using prepared statements if you do `$sQuery = " UPDATE $sTable SET  $colUpdate = '$valUpdate' WHERE  id = $id";`? With `$valUpdate` being user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use encodeURIComponent(sValue).

Also consider using some kind of SQL-injection free syntax like prepared statements.