# IDN aware tools to encode/decode human readable IRI to/from valid URI

Tags: javascript, python, html, idn, iri

Let's assume a user enter address of some resource and we need to translate it to:

```
<a href="valid URI here">human readable form</a>
```

HTML4 specification refers to [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html) which allows only ASCII alphanumeric characters and dash in host part and all non-ASCII character in other parts should be percent-encoded. That's what I want to put in href attribute to make link working properly in all browsers. IDN should be encoded with [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).

HTML5 draft refers to [RFC 3987](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3987.html) which also allows percent-encoded unicode characters in host part and a large subset of unicode in both host and other parts without encoding them. User may enter address in any of these forms. To provide human readable form of it I need to decode all printable characters. Note that some parts of address might not correspond to valid UTF-8 sequences, usually when target site uses some other character encoding.

An example of what I'd like to get:

```
<a href="http://xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C?%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81">
http://сайт.рф/путь?запрос</a>
```

Are there any tools to solve these tasks? I'm especially interested in libraries for Python and JavaScript.

**Update**: I know there is a way to do percent and Punycode (without proper normalization, but I can live with it) encoding/decoding in Python and JavaScript. The whole task needs much more work and there are some pitfalls (some characters should be always encoded or never encoded depending on context). I wonder if there are ready to use libraries for the *whole* problem, since it seems to be quite common and modern browsers already do such conversions (try typing `http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/`  in Google Chrome and it will be replaced with `http://сайт.рф/`, but use `Host: xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai` in HTTP request).

**Update2**: Vinay Sajip pointed that Werkzeug has iri_to_uri and uri_to_iri functions that handles most cases correctly. I've found only 2 cases where it fails so far: percent-encoded host (quite easy to fix) and invalid utf-8 sequences (it's a bit tricky to do nicely, but shouldn't be a problem).

I'm still looking for library in JavaScript. It's not hard to write, but I'd prefer to avoid inventing the wheel.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-free-javascript-for-punycode-to-unicode-conversion

Comment: Thanks for the link. The question is not about just Punycode encoding implementation (it's easy), but a much bigger problem.

Comment: Then you should probably clarify as I still don't get what you are asking for.

Comment: I added a link in my answer to a Javascript implementation, which can perhaps be adapted to your needs. It's public domain but needs unit tests, I would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you can use the batteries included in Python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib
import urlparse

URL1 = u'http://сайт.рф/путь?запрос'
URL2 = 'http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/'

def to_idn(url):
    parts = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))
    parts[1] = parts[1].encode('idna')
    parts[2:] = [urllib.quote(s.encode('utf-8')) for s in parts[2:]]
    return urlparse.urlunparse(parts)

def from_idn(url):
    return urllib.unquote(url)

print to_idn(URL1)
print from_idn(URL2)
print to_idn(from_idn(URL2).decode('utf-8'))
```

which prints

```
http://xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C?%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81
http://сайт.рф/
http://xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai/
```

which looks like what you want. I'm not sure what special cases you mean - perhaps you could give some examples of the pitfalls you're referring to?

**Update:** I just remembered, Werkzeug has [`iri_to_uri`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/documentation/dev/utils.html#werkzeug.iri_to_uri) and [`uri_to_iri`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/documentation/dev/utils.html#werkzeug.uri_to_iri) functions in versions 0.6 and later (links are to the relevant part of the docs).

**Further update:** Sorry, I hadn't noticed that you're looking for a JavaScript implementation as well as a Python one. An existing public domain Javascript implementation of punycode is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-free-javascript-for-punycode-to-unicode-conversion). I can't vouch for it, though. And of course you can use the built-in JavaScript `encodeURI`/`decodeURI` APIs.

Comment: Your functions work for this example only. Werkzeug functions works for most cases and can be easily fixed for the rest, thanks!

Comment: Your coding line has -*' instead of -*-. To avoid this mess you can just write
# coding: utf-8