# How to convert domain names with greek characters to an ascii URL?

Tags: url, character-encoding, ascii, punycode

For example:

When typing παιχνιδια.com into Firefox, it is automatically converted to xn--kxadblxczv9d.com

Please suggest a tool for making such a conversion.

---

One of the easiest is [this](http://www.saferwhois.com). Converts and checks for availability at the same time.

Comment: What type of tool? Command line? A web site? A class or code? If so in what language?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

Comment: I meant an online tool. Got an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any tool that supports "Libidn". A quick search showed [SimpleDNS](http://www.simpledns.com/addons.aspx) might be of help to you.

There are heaps of converters for IDN online, if that's enough for you, you can use [one](http://mct.verisign-grs.com/) of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it inside your browser, save the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-free-javascript-for-punycode-to-unicode-conversion/301287#301287) as **puny.js** and the code below to **puny.html**, then load the file in your browser.

```
<html>
    <title>Punyconverter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="puny.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        input {width:300px;}
        label {width:100px; display:inline-block;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        onload = function( ) {
            var ASCII = document.getElementById("ASCII");
            var Unicode = document.getElementById("Unicode");
            var Input = document.getElementById("Input");

            Input.onkeyup=function(){
                ASCII.value = punycode.ToASCII( this.value);
                Unicode.value = punycode.ToUnicode( this.value);
            }
        };
    </script>
</html>
<body>
    <h1>Convert puny coded IDN</h1>
    <div><label for="Input">Input</label><input id="Input" type="text"></div>
    <div><label for="ASCII">ASCII</label><input id="ASCII" type="text" readonly="readonly"></div>
    <div><label for="Unicode">Unicode</label><input id="Unicode" type="text" readonly="readonly"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Internationalized domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (i.e. domain names with non-ASCII characters) are encoded using the [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) system.

Answer (score 1):

You encode and decode IDNA [with Python](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html):

```
>>> print u'παιχνιδια'.encode('idna')
xn--mxaaitabzv9d
>>> print 'xn--mxaaitabzv9d'.decode('idna')
παιχνιδια
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard modules in Perl also in Apache can do it with the URI module.

```
use URI;
#insert sitename in next:
$sitename = "..";
my $uri = URI->new( $sitename,'http');
if ($uri->scheme) { print $uri; }
```