# Using charCodeAt(0) for an emoji returns wrong number

Tags: javascript, unicode

The following doesn't seem correct

```
"".charCodeAt(0);  // returns 55357 in both Firefox and Chrome
```

That's a Unicode character named ROCKET (U+1F680), the decimal should be 128640.

This is for a unicode app am writing. Seems most but not ALL chars from unicode 6 all stuck at 55357.

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: @XahLee, it was a comment, not an answer. Please mark the best *answer* as accepted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript is using UTF-16 encoding; see [this article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding) for details:

> Characters outside the BMP, e.g. U+1D306 tetragram for centre (), can only be encoded in UTF-16 using two 16-bit code units: 0xD834
>   0xDF06. This is called a surrogate pair. Note that a surrogate pair
>   only represents a single character.
>
> The first code unit of a surrogate pair is always in the range from
>   0xD800 to 0xDBFF, and is called a high surrogate or a lead surrogate.
>
> The second code unit of a surrogate pair is always in the range from
>   0xDC00 to 0xDFFF, and is called a low surrogate or a trail surrogate.

You can decode the surrogate pair like this:

```
codePoint = (text.charCodeAt(0) - 0xD800) * 0x400 + text.charCodeAt(1) - 0xDC00 + 0x10000
```

Complete code can be found can be found in the [Mozilla documentation for charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

Comment: all great answers. Josh Lee's link to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt , which contain code to fix the problem.

Comment: Daniel, would you consider adding that Mozilla link? as it contains working code. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Tried this out:

```
> "".charCodeAt(0);
55357

> "".charCodeAt(1);
56960
```

Related questions on SO:

- [Expressing UTF-16 unicode characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126384/expressing-utf-16-unicode-characters-in-javascript)
- [Unicode characters from charcode in javascript for charcodes > 0xFFFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446492/unicode-characters-from-charcode-in-javascript-for-charcodes-0xffff)

You might want to take a look at this too:

- [Getting it to work with higher values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because they're returning you the first code unit UTF-16 encoding of that character. I'm not sure there's much you can do, because they're returning a 16-bit value -- I would probably try manually decoding the character from the first two code units and then encoding it in UTF-32, which seems to be what you want.