# charCodeAt and fromCharCode do not return the same character

Tags: javascript, char, tampermonkey, fromcharcode

In theory, no matter what the input is, the output should be unchanged:

```
String.fromCharCode("a".charCodeAt(0));    //"a"
```

This makes sense because I'm just trying to get the char code of a character, and then casting it back to a character.

However when I try with this character, it breaks:

```
//"": 55356
String.fromCharCode("".charCodeAt(0));    //"�" (65533)
```

[image]

<sup>(Note that I actually highlighted the string and pasted it into the next line. It changed to `�` by itself for some reason.)</sup>

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

I noticed that there is a new method in ES6, `String.fromCodePoint()` but it is not supported every browser except Firefox.

Comment: @user1281385 - Wow, that's in Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry yeah I was trying to delete when you commented

Comment: Probably a better link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446492/unicode-characters-from-charcode-in-javascript-for-charcodes-0xffff

Comment: Try console out `String.fromCharCode("".charCodeAt(0)).charCodeAt(0)` -> http://jsfiddle.net/9bLxB/

Comment: Are you sure your files are UTF-8 encoded?  Depending on the dev environment and your settings, that may not be the case. (Might want to go ahead and edit your tags, too.)

Comment: @JeremyMiller - I don't know since this is actually a part of my script in [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/). I'm trying to insert `` into the document but it comes out as the "replacement character" as [xdazz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz) mentioned. Then I tried saving the script with their charCode and converting it back later. Now here's how I get into this problem. Whenever I try to put this character into the document it changes to `�`.

Comment: Haven't worked with that environment before, but I'd check encoding for sure.  Everytime I've had such an issue it's because of encoding... DB, webpage, Java, or otherwise.

Comment: @JeremyMiller - After doing some experiments, it seems like if I directly do `inputelement.value = ""` it works. But when I store it in an object `{"a":""}` it doesn't return the correct character.

Comment: Wow.  I'd add that to the main part of your post b/c it's def informative.  Unfortunately, that also takes it out of my experience on these issues.  Only time I've seen such behavior is when the function isn't UTF-8 compat, but an object isn't a function, lol!

Comment: Still, `console.log("".charCodeAt(0),   String.fromCharCode("".charCodeAt(0)).charCodeAt(0));` gives 55356 55356 http://jsfiddle.net/9bLxB/1/ so what is the problem really,, it does not break?

Comment: @davidkonrad - Yes, I realized that there is nothing wrong with this part. Perhaps I should reformulate my question.

Answer (score 4):

It does not change.

```
> String.fromCharCode("".charCodeAt(0)).charCodeAt(0)
  55356
```

And you can check all by:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 65535; i++) {
   if (String.fromCharCode(i).charCodeAt(0) !== i) {
       console.log('error', i, String.fromCharCode(i)); 
   }
}
```

Why you saw `�` is because `�`(65533) is
used to replace a character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in unicode.

It is called **[REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm)**.