# location.href on a domain with umlaut (ü) reports different domain

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, domain-name

Visiting the following domain:
[https://obs.bürgerhaus.de](https://obs.b%C3%BCrgerhaus.de)

In the browser console, if I check `document.location.href`, I get the following returned:

```
> document.location.href
"https://obs.xn--brgerhaus-q9a.de/"
```

Why is this value different than the actual domain? Is this some type of url encoding or something? How do I get the original domain with the umlaut in it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name it is punycode encoded to keep URLs limited to ASCII as they were from the beginning - To parse it back, this library could help: https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/ or look at this solution from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/301287/3977134

Comment: @r3dst0rm Thanks. You can post the answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Domain Name System, which performs a lookup service to translate
>   user-friendly names into network addresses for locating Internet
>   resources, is restricted in practice[1](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/idn-in-google-chrome) to the use of ASCII
>   characters, a practical limitation that initially set the standard for
>   acceptable domain names.

(see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)

As the article tells, domains we use everyday, are technically limited to ASCII characters, to support more characters unicode domains gets encoded into so called `Punycode` (see RFC: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3492.txt)

Visting a website with an umlaut (or similar) will force the browser to encode this. For example, [http://öbb.at](http://%C3%B6bb.at) is transformed to http://xn--bb-eka.at. The transformed form is called ASCII Compatible Encoding (ACE) made up of the four character prefix ( xn-- ) and the punycode representation of Unicode characters. [See more details here ...](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/idn-in-google-chrome)

To parse it back, you could look into:

[Punycode JS on GitHub](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js)

[Solution from some - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/301287/3977134)